# Debug bot on local machine via ngrok and vpn

Tags: asp.net-core, telegram, vpn, telegram-bot, ngrok

I want to debug a simple bot for telegram on my local machine.

I use Telegram.Bot and web hooks on asp.net core 3.0. I am from Russia and Telegram is blocked in my country, so I need to use a VPN if I want to connect to the Telegram API via Telegram.Bot.

I started ngrok but ran into a problem. Telegram post requests do not arrive on my local machine. But the get requests that I do myself on ngrok come correctly.

I run ngrok with the command: `ngrok http 54823 -host-header="localhost:54823"`. 54823 - my default debug port in vs, not ssl.

I get an url: `https://5bf38bda.ngrok.io`

Then I make requests: `get: https://5bf38bda.ngrok.io/api/message/update` and it activates breakpoint. Then I make a `post` from the Telegram client and nothing happens.

In ngrok web interface i see next picture: [get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuUli.png)
[post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZf3m.png)

X-Forwarded-For field is different for get(uses ip vpn) and post(uses unknown ip) requests. Could this be the problem? 
Can I use ngrok with vpn this way? Or will it only work without vpn? Need help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here: [telegram currently supports the following ports: 443, 80, 88 and 8443](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1045833/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ngrok-%D0%B8-vpn)

I changed the port in launchSettings.jso to 443 and this solved the problem.